# Can't set headers already sent node.js/express

Tags: node.js, express

Whenever I go this URL for the second time, I always get

> can't set headers already sent

```
app.post('/auth/facebook', function(req, res, next) {
    // What should I do with the access token?
    User.findOne({ facebook: req.body.facebookId}, function(err, user) {
      // if user does exist then simply send the token back to the client
      if (user) {
        return res.send({ token: createJWT(user) })
      }
      // if user doesnt exist
      var user = new User();
      user.email = req.body.email;
      user.facebook = req.body.facebookId;
      user.first_name = req.body.first_name;
      user.last_name = req.body.last_name;
      user.save(function(err) {
        return res.send({ token: createJWT(user)})
      });
    });

  });
```

Is it because I send the token twice?

Comment: It doesn't seem that problem in this code. Probably, you have middleware that sent headers bebore this code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this error occurs because you are using the res.send to set response headers twice. The first time you set them, even if it is inside the if bracket, it is the normal use scenario (most times you will have a user returned) so, the second time you call it (this is always executed), you have already set them(when user exists - that is most of the times). 
I think that happens with any response headers, such as `res.json` that KibGzr suggested. That as general advice. Concerning your problem, I would bracket the scenario that there is no user, and inside that I would execute the logic of creating the new user. Then outside the bracket, I would set the headers, as I would always want to sent the token. Like this :

```
app.post('/auth/facebook', function(req, res, next) {
    // What should I do with the access token?
    User.findOne({ facebook: req.body.facebookId}, function(err, user) {
      // if user doesnt exist create one
      if (!user) {
        var user = new User();
        user.email = req.body.email;
        user.facebook = req.body.facebookId;
        user.first_name = req.body.first_name;
        user.last_name = req.body.last_name;
        user.save(function(err) {
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
          }
      });
      //Then send the token as a user exists anyway
      return res.send({ token: createJWT(user) }); 
    }
  });
```

So the general idea is, set the headers **once** per scenario - make sure no response is set twice per scenario. Hope I helped.

Comment: If user exists, code execution will be interrupted because of `return`. So the second `res.send` will never be called

Comment: It's true, but I would change the structure of the code anyway. The fact is that he does want to send the token in any scenario. The different scenarios are when a user exists or not. So execute code according to that, and use the response in the end as the user exists anyway. I'm also not a fan of the if-else structure suggested above as it uses the same response twice as well.

Answer (score 0):

The user object can be either null or a user.Put the logic inside a `if else` block makes it easier to read the code.Always console log the user object and req.body while dealing with authentication and signing up logic.Makes your life easier.

```
app.post('/auth/facebook', function (req, res, next) {
// What should I do with the access token?
User.findOne({facebook: req.body.facebookId}, function (err, user) {
    // if user does exist then simply send the token back to the client
    console.log(user);
    if (user != null) {
        return res.send({token: createJWT(user)})
    } else {
        // if user doesnt exist
        var user = new User();
        user.email = req.body.email;
        user.facebook = req.body.facebookId;
        user.first_name = req.body.first_name;
        user.last_name = req.body.last_name;
        user.save(function (err) {
            return res.send({token: createJWT(user)})
        });
    }
});
```